# Unable to get value when using dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect in XPages

Tags: dojo, xpages

In my XPage I have `xp:comboBox` with `dojoType` set to `dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect`. When I try to get its value in SSJS using `getComponent("comboBox1").getValue()` it returns `null`. If I remove the `dojoType` then the code works.

Here's the complete code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/form/resources/CheckedMultiSelect.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:comboBox id="comboBox1" dojoType="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect">
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Untitled 1"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Untitled 2"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Untitled 3"></xp:selectItem>
    </xp:comboBox>
    <xp:comboBox id="comboBox2">
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Untitled 1"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Untitled 2"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Untitled 3"></xp:selectItem>
    </xp:comboBox>
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("============ " + getComponent("comboBox1").getValue());
print("============ " + getComponent("comboBox2").getValue());}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

I the above code `comboBox1` has `dojoType` set to `dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect` while `comboBox2` is plain combo box. On click of button value of `comboBox2` is printed on console while for `comboBox1` it prints null.

Why does this happen? What can I do to get the value from `comboBox1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume it has something to do with how dojo rewrites this control to achieve this. If you take a look at the source generated, the combo box is something like:

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    ...
</select>
```

This is not how the dojo control is rendered it is broken up into many divs inside each other I'm guessing .getValue() just has no idea how to process that. You will need to do this client side with dojo script. The way it seems to work is that inside a number of divs is a div with

```
data-dojo-attach-point="wrapperDiv"
```

and inside that div are a number of divs one for each option, the selcted one's div having an attribute `aria-selected="true"` , you will have to search for this and get the value from inside.

That is unless you can find something in the dojo documentation that details how to pull out the value (I can't)

**Update 29-Jun-2012 (Naveen):**

Thanks Simon, you were absolutely right about the Dojo rewriting. I was able to get the selected value using client side javascript using the below code:

```
dijit.byId("#{id:comboBox1}").get("value")
```

I am putting the selected value in a field using the `onClick` event and then getting that field value in server side javascript. I know its lot of work for a simple thing, but it works. If you have a better solution then do share.

Comment: I noticed you already found the answer yourself :) one improvement (as my example shows) might be **setting** and **getting** the value of your "helperField" in the submitEvent from the button. If the user doesn't click any radiobutton _and_ no defaultValue is set, no data will be set (eventhough one is selected) in the "helperField" since the onClick event isn't triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The dojoType you refer to, doesn't have a SS getValue() yet. Getting the value CS is however fairly simple using dijit.byId("id").getValue(). With the help of a hiddenInput you have your workaround. I pasted the example below:

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox1" dojoType="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Untitled 1"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Untitled 2"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Untitled 3"></xp:selectItem>
</xp:comboBox>

<xp:inputHidden id="inputHidden1"></xp:inputHidden>

<xp:button value="Label" id="button5">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            print("Submitting: " + getComponent("inputHidden1").getValue());
        }]]></xp:this.action>
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[dojo.byId("#{id:inputHidden1}").value = dijit.byId("#{id:comboBox1}").getValue();]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```